# numerical output expected, ConditionSet() returned

Tags: python, sympy

I'm working on my master's thesis where I've encountered a problem with trying to program a formula to calculate the payback period of a solar installation taking the rising energy prices into consideration.

the code I've used is as follows:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
Eq1 = x
Eq2 = 3 / (1 * (1 + 0.02)**x)
print(solveset(Eq2 - Eq1, x))
```

When I try to run this program I get returned a ConditionSet(), which is strange since there should be just 1 solution for the TVT (payback period).

Comment: What library is involved here?!

Comment: I used the sympy library, I'm pretty new to coding and I'm self thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you used `solveset`, which returns a set as output. Now, you could try to use `solve`, but in this case it would raise a `NotImplementedError`.

Since you are interested to a numerical solution, you can try `nsolve` and provide an initial guess:

```
# solve Eq2 - Eq1=0 for x, taking 2 as the initial guess
nsolve(Eq2 - Eq1, x, 2)
# out: 2.8361542122017
```

You can plot your equation to find an appropriate initial guess:

```
plot(Eq2 - Eq1)
```

Comment: I've tried it and it works! I made the numerical guess dynamic since it is dependent on the "3" and "1"  which are also dynamic values in the code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great, don't forget to mark this answer as the solution to your question.